# How may I render my nav bar component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Consider:

#### File *App.js*

```javascript
import './App.css';
import {Link,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import {Login} from "./login";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/*" element={<Login />}/>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

#### File *index.js*

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {RoutPart} from './routPart';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

#### File *routPart.js*

```javascript
import {Link,Route,Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import {Home} from "./home";
import {Dashboard} from "./dashboard";

export function RoutPart(props){
    return(
        <>
            <div>
                <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
            </div>
            <div>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard userData={props.userData}/>}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard/>}/>
                    <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>hello</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

#### File *login.js*

```javascript
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { RoutPart } from "./routPart";
var ReactDOM=require("react-dom");

export function Login(){
    let [id,setUserId]=useState("");
    let [password,setPassword]=useState("");

    let handelSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let url=`http://localhost:8000/login/${id}/${password}`;
        axios.get(url)
        .then((res)=>{
            if(res.data.msg=="No data found !!!!!"){
                console.log("ndf")
            }else{
                ReactDOM.render(<RoutPart data={res.data}/>,document.getElementById("abc"));

            }
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
        })
    }

    return(
        <div id="abc">
            <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
                <label>Enter your ID:</label>
                <input type="text" name="id" className="form-control" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your ID here....."
                onChange={(e)=>setUserId(e.target.value)}></input>
                <br/>
                <label>Enter your password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" className="form-control" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your password here....."
                onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}></input>
                <button name="login">ok</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### File *dashboard.js*

```javascript
export function Dashboard(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>hiiiiiii</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

#### File *home.js*

```javascript
export function Home(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>home</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am new in React, and I want to built an app, where I want to render the nav bar items after successfully login.

Before log in, there will not be any nav bar. For that I use "/*" for routeing through the components in App.js. When I run this code, it is showing the login form, but when I click on the "ok" button it is showing a blank page and this above code it is giving this error. How to solve that? Note: The API is ok and giving the user data; please ignore isLogin operations.

#### Error

```
Uncaught Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (router.ts:5:1)
    at useHref (hooks.tsx:32:1)
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:267:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
invariant @ router.ts:5
useHref @ hooks.tsx:32
LinkWithRef @ index.tsx:267
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
(anonymous) @ login.js:18
Promise.then (async)
handelSubmit @ login.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
router.ts:5 Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (router.ts:5:1)
    at useRoutes (hooks.tsx:270:1)
    at Routes (components.tsx:256:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
invariant @ router.ts:5
useRoutes @ hooks.tsx:270
Routes @ components.tsx:256
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
(anonymous) @ login.js:18
Promise.then (async)
handelSubmit @ login.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
2react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

    at LinkWithRef (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41637:5)
    at div
    at RoutPart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:656:29)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
(anonymous) @ login.js:18
Promise.then (async)
handelSubmit @ login.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Routes> component:

    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42793:5)
    at div
    at RoutPart (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:656:29)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
(anonymous) @ login.js:18
Promise.then (async)
handelSubmit @ login.js:13
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
login.js:23 Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
    at invariant (router.ts:5:1)
    at useHref (hooks.tsx:32:1)
    at LinkWithRef (index.tsx:267:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

Comment: I'm surprised the 'Ok' button does anything at all, since it has no click event attached to it. Are you missing some code perhaps?

Comment: That said, I'd recommend not putting code like `ReactDOM.render()` in the server response callback. Put a conditional or dynamic block of code in your component's JSX instead, or if you want to navigate to a page by means of the router, you'll need to do something like `this.router.to('/somepage')`

Comment: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) are not for general formatting, only if it actually runs. See e.g. *[Stack Snippets being misused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused)*.

Answer (score 0):

So one way to do this is to have two path's wrapped in the Routes element, one for login and then another for all your home paths.  The home path will take an element called layout, which will have your nav bar and then the nested routes within that route will be able to interchange depending on the path selected.

```
import {
 BrowserRouter as Router,
 Routes,
 Route,
 Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";

return (
 <div>
   <Router>
     <Routes>
       {/* //we set up a conditional check using a ternerary operator to see whether 
       //user is logged in or not.  If logged in, redirect to home page */}
       <Route
         path="/login"
         element={!user ? <Login /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />}
       />
       {/* //we have Layout component built which contains our nav bar and all the nested Routes
         //are swappable within that.  Add whatever user checks here also */}
       <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
         <Route index element={<Home />} />
         <Route path="nestedpath" element={<NestedComponent />} />
         <Route path="othernestedpath" element={<OtherNestedComponent/>}/>
         
       </Route>
     </Routes>
   </Router>
 </div>
);

//in components section create module create for your layout
import { outlet } from "react-router-dom";
//import navbar from components etc
function Layout() {
 return (
   <div>
     <Navbar />
     {/* //Outlet is a placeholder for all the nested route components */}
     <Outlet />
   </div>
 );
}

export default Layout;
```